# Hello I’m trying to set up a gta server but I’m getting this error

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto

```
[    script:mrp-gangs] SCRIPT ERROR: @mrp-gangs/server.lua:822: attempt to index a nil value (local 'xKiller')
```

[    script:mrp-gangs] > handler (@ReaperAC/server.lua:5)

```
RegisterServerEvent('asd:onPlayerDeath')
AddEventHandler('asd:onPlayerDeath', function(data)
    if data.killedByPlayer then
        local xKiller = ASD.GetPlayerFromId(data.killerServerId)
        TriggerClientEvent('asd_gangs:playerKilled', data.killerServerId)
    end
end)
 
RegisterServerEvent('asd_gangs:sumPlayerKill')
AddEventHandler('asd_gangs:sumPlayerKill', function(id)
    local xKiller = ASD.GetPlayerFromId(id)
    MySQL.Sync.execute("UPDATE users SET kills = kills + 1 WHERE identifier = @identifier", {['@identifier'] = xKiller.getIdentifier()})
end)
```

Comment: Which GTA/mod? Tag [tag:grand-theft-auto] is not appropriate to use, as no GTA ever contained native Lua support.

Answer (score 0):

`ASD.GetPlayerFromId()` is returning **nil**. Are you sure `data.killerServerId` is valid, or even exists?

One possible solution would be to check that the player with the `provided ID` actually exists beforehand and, if not, then handle it differently.